# Method call on clap::App moving ownership more than once

Tags: rust, ownership, clap

Even after reading the chapters about reference ownership and borrowing, I  cannot understand some things in the following code, effectively stopping me from calling more than one method from `clap::App`!

```
extern crate clap;

use clap::App;

fn main() {
    let mut app =
        App::new("name me").args_from_usage("<input_file>          'Sets the input file to use'");
    let matches = app.get_matches();
    app.print_help();
    println!(
        "Using input file: {}",
        matches.value_of("input_file").unwrap()
    );
}
```

Compiling this code leads to:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `app`
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
8 |     let matches = app.get_matches();
  |                   --- value moved here
9 |     app.print_help();
  |     ^^^ value used here after move
  |
  = note: move occurs because `app` has type `clap::App<'_, '_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

1. If I understand correctly, `app.get_matches()` asks to borrow the ownership, thus `app` must be `mut`. Where does the ownership go once the function returns?
2. I thought `app` would still have ownership of the object, yet the compiler has a different opinion.

How can I get the matches, and effectively still call another method, such as `print_help` on `app` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [function signature for `App::get_matches`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.19.1/clap/struct.App.html#method.get_matches):

```
fn get_matches(self) -> ArgMatches<'a>
```

This takes `self` by value, also said as it *consumes* the value; you *cannot* call any methods on it afterwards. There's nothing to be done about this; presumably the author has good rationale for this.

Now review [`App::print_help`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.19.1/clap/struct.App.html#method.print_help):

```
fn print_help(&mut self) -> ClapResult<()>
```

It takes a reference (which happens to be mutable). You do not have to transfer ownership to call this method.

---

> If I understand correctly, `app.get_matches()` asks to borrow the ownership, thus app must be `mut`. Where does the ownership go once the function returns?

You do not understand correctly, in multiple dimensions.

1. `get_matches` consumes the value, it does not borrow anything.
2. A value does not need to be mutable to be borrowed.
3. When you do borrow something, the ownership doesn't "go" anywhere. The original owner continues to own it. That's why it's called *borrowing*.

> How can I get the matches, and effectively still call another method, such as `print_help` on app then?

You don't. The obvious workaround is to clone the original object, producing a second value. Then you can consume one value and still call methods on the second value.

---

Basically, it sounds like you are trying to do something that the library is discouraging you from doing. Perhaps you should re-evaluate your goals and/or review the intended usage of the library. For example, `get_matches` will automatically display the help text when the user requests it, so why should your code try to do so?

From the [Clap issue tracker](https://github.com/kbknapp/clap-rs/issues/785):

> You have a few options. You can either use [`AppSettings::ArgRequiredElseHelp`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.19.2/clap/enum.AppSettings.html#variant.ArgRequiredElseHelp) or you can keep the move from happening by using [`App::get_matches_from_safe_borrow`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.19.2/clap/struct.App.html#method.get_matches_from_safe_borrow).

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on my big misunderstanding here! It's just a strange feeling on some point Rust, at first…

Comment: @Jiehong yeah, there's definitely a learning curve, but pretty much everything has a good reason for existing. In this case, I wish I could explain exactly why this library is designed like this. The best I can provide is that `clap::App` documentation refers to itself as a builder. Generally, once you have built something, the builder is consumed in the process.

Comment: @Shepmaster nicely explained. May I add this: many command line tools show full help on a 'bare' command invocation, including `java` and `cloc`. So I see it as reasonable for @Jiehong to want clap to provide a full help message. I have not yet found a simple way to provide this behavior with clap.

Comment: @DavidJames certainly, although that sounds like a case for a feature request for clap itself. My point is mostly that clap has chosen to be opinionated in design, hopefully for a good reason. Going with the flow will make using a library easier. ^_^

Comment: Re: "presumably the author has good rationale for this" ... I asked directly on the Clap issue tracker: https://github.com/kbknapp/clap-rs/issues/785

Answer (score 0):

I had to show the help in some situations and it was really a p*i*t*a™.

So, my last solution was:

```
let app = Command::new("app") ...
let matches = app.clone().get_matches();
```

...

```
let show_help = || {
    let mut app_mut = app.clone();
    let _ = app_mut.print_long_help();
};
```

...

Now I can `show_help()` whenever I want.

I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing, this seems bizarre, but it was the way I managed to solve it without pulling my hair out.