# Is there any straightforward way for Clap to display help when no command is provided?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I'm using [the Clap crate](https://crates.io/crates/clap) for parsing command line parameters. I've defined a subcommand `ls` that should list files. Clap also defines a `help` subcommand that displays information about the application and its usage.

If no command is provided, nothing gets displayed at all, but I want the app to display help in that case.

I've tried this code, which looks pretty straightforward, but it doesn't work:

```
extern crate clap;

use clap::{App, SubCommand};

fn main() {
    let mut app = App::new("myapp")
        .version("0.0.1")
        .about("My first CLI APP")
        .subcommand(SubCommand::with_name("ls").about("List anything"));
    let matches = app.get_matches();

    if let Some(cmd) = matches.subcommand_name() {
        match cmd {
            "ls" => println!("List something here"),
            _ => eprintln!("unknown command"),
        }
    } else {
        app.print_long_help();
    }
}
```

I get an error that `app` is used after move:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `app`
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
10 |     let matches = app.get_matches();
   |                   --- value moved here
...
18 |         app.print_long_help();
   |         ^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `app` has type `clap::App<'_, '_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Reading through the documentation of Clap, I've found that the `clap::ArgMatches` that's returned in `get_matches()` has a method [`usage`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.31.1/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.usage) that returns the string for usage part, but, unfortunately, only this part and nothing else.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`clap::AppSettings::ArgRequiredElseHelp`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.31.1/clap/enum.AppSettings.html#variant.ArgRequiredElseHelp):

```
App::new("myprog")
    .setting(AppSettings::ArgRequiredElseHelp)
```

See also:

- [Method call on clap::App moving ownership more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40951538/155423)

Comment: thanks for your answer. It works great! Also, thanks for the related answer. Found a lot of useful information there.

Comment: Just note that: "`Setting Arg::default_value` effectively disables this option as it will ensure that some argument is always present." `SubcommandRequiredElseHelp` might be a better option for some apps.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the **derive instead of the builder API** you can set the flag mentioned by shepmaster as follows:

```
#[command(arg_required_else_help = true)]
pub struct Cli {

    #[clap(short)]
    pub init: bool,
```

See also: https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/_tutorial/index.html#configuring-the-parser

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`Command::arg_required_else_help`](https://docs.rs/clap/4.4.8/clap/struct.Command.html#method.arg_required_else_help) as a `bool` on the command itself.

```
Command::new("rule").arg_required_else_help(true)
```

Comment: @PéterSzilvási Thanks for the link fix, but instead of creating another link that may break, why not use a permalink: https://docs.rs/clap/4.4.8/clap/struct.Command.html#method.arg_required_else_help

Comment: Just approved @Péter-Szilvási's edit that pins the ref to the 4.4.8 docs