# How can I display help after calling Clap's get_matches?

Tags: rust, clap

I'm having the same problem as [Is there any straightforward way for Clap to display help when no command is provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290526/is-there-any-straightforward-way-for-clap-to-display-help-when-no-command-is-pro), but the solution proposed in that question is not good enough for me.

`.setting(AppSettings::ArgRequiredElseHelp)` stops the program if no arguments are provided, and I need the program to carry on execution even if no arguments are provided. I need the help to be displayed in addition.

Comment: stupid question but why ?

Comment: So you just want [`print_help`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.App.html#method.print_help)/[`print_long_help`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.App.html#method.print_long_help)?

Comment: @Stargateur I need to run migrations even if the program isn't executed (otherwise the tests would not run). If you have a better idea let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the string before.

```
use clap::{App, SubCommand};

use std::str;

fn main() {
    let mut app = App::new("myapp")
        .version("0.0.1")
        .about("My first CLI APP")
        .subcommand(SubCommand::with_name("ls").about("List anything"));

    let mut help = Vec::new();
    app.write_long_help(&mut help).unwrap();

    let _ = app.get_matches();

    println!("{}", str::from_utf8(&help).unwrap());
}
```

Or you could use [`get_matches_safe`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.31.1/clap/struct.App.html#method.get_matches_safe:)

```
use clap::{App, AppSettings, ErrorKind, SubCommand};

fn main() {
    let app = App::new("myapp")
        .setting(AppSettings::ArgRequiredElseHelp)
        .version("0.0.1")
        .about("My first CLI APP")
        .subcommand(SubCommand::with_name("ls").about("List anything"));

    let matches = app.get_matches_safe();

    match matches {
        Err(e) => {
            if e.kind == ErrorKind::MissingArgumentOrSubcommand {
                println!("{}", e.message)
            }
        }
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up rewriting my program so now I'm using the ArgsRequiredElseHelp. I hope the answer comes useful to other people though.

Comment: @OmarAbid my answer was not enough for your case ? I through it was.

Comment: @Stragateur Your answer was enough and in fact it is a valid solution. However, looking again at the code I decided that I could do a better architecture and I ended up writing it so that it adheres to Clap instead of trying to work around it.